# com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: PRIMARY KEY part sequence found in SET part

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am trying to update the table, then i am getting this exception:

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: PRIMARY KEY part sequence found in SET part.

My table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS STYLINGBEE.LKPSTYLES(
    STYLEID ASCII,
    NAME ASCII,
    IMAGE ASCII,
    SEQUENCE INT,
    ACTIVE BOOLEAN,
    PRIMARY KEY (STYLEID,SEQUENCE)
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (SEQUENCE DESC);
```

Comment: strange, have you created key-space or not? if yes then use that key space and instead of STYLINGBEE.LKPSTYLES directly use your table-name, it's just and guess. not sure whether it will help or not.

Comment: Although submitted by different users, this question asks about the same problem on the *same exact schema* as this question that I answered 30 minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075596/how-to-update-clustering-key-in-cassandra-using-update-query/27078376#27078376 I can't mark either as a duplicate without an accepted, or upvoted answer.

Answer (score 10):

While having your complete query would help, I can tell from the error message that you are trying to `UPDATE` a row's `PRIMARY KEY`.  From the [DataStax documentation on the UPDATE command](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/update_r.html):

```
The UPDATE SET operation is not valid on a primary key field.
```

This is why you are getting this particular error message.  If you have inserted a row containing a part of the primary key that you need to update, you will have to remove that row and re-insert it.

Comment: Yep, at this case - this is exactly what he received, I just researched some workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Cassandra don't allow you to update primary key.
You can not do something like below because SEQUENCE is part of primary key.

UPDATE STYLINGBEE.LKPSTYLES SET SEQUENCE = 1 WHERE STYLEID = 1000;

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying  to update some row without STYLEID specified in your query (WHERE part). Could you please publish your CQL statement.
I think this one link could help you: [Why doesn't my Cassandra update work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36380513/why-doesnt-my-cassandra-update-work)